# Python Scrapy modify spider from extension

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to modify my spider start_requests method from custom extension. The main goal is to send url to spider when I get response from my custom api. But method that I handed to spider doesnt run. Maybe its not good practice. 
Also I read scrapy documentation about crawler engine, maybe its would be better to mange spider from extension, like `spider.parse(Request(url))`. But I dont see any examples of usage that attempts to my goal or something like. 
Here is code example:

```
class GetUrl(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ext = cls()

        # connect the extension object to signals
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
        # return the extension object
        return ext

   def spider_opened(self, spider):
        print(spider.name)
        spider.start_requests = self.start

   def spider_idle(self, spider):
        raise DontCloseSpider

   def spider_closed(self, spider):
        logger.info("closed spider %s", spider.name)

   def start():
        yield scrapy.Request('https://example.com', dont_filter=True)
```

P.S. Scrapy doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/456 and linked issues?